# microsoft jet oledb 4.0 provider is not registered on the local machine Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I have installed following Redistributable for 64 bit
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Still same problem.

IIS Server 7.5
Office 2013 64 Bit
Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard64 Bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing IIS App Pool settings.
1.  Open IIS manager and select the application pool corresponding to your application.
2.  Right click on your Application Pool.
3.  Select Advanced Settings. 
4.  Select an option Enable 32-bit Applications and change option to true.
5.  Once you set this property restart your application pool.